# Google sheets api getting specific sheet notes

Tags: bash, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I managed to get first sheet notes in some spreadsheet using:

```
curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
         "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$SPREADSHEET_ID?fields=sheets%2Fdata%2FrowData%2Fvalues%2Fnote"
```

But how about getting the notes of some sheet? not only the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the response contains array of sheets with the release notes of each one